# Index Design | Performance of Multiple Indexes VS 1 Index with multiple Data Sources

Tags: c#, saas, azure-cognitive-search

Implementing Azure Search. We currently got two tables (Relational DB) related to each other that we would like to use as an Index.

What's the best way to implement this?

1. Hitting Two indexes (One for each table), do the join between the
   results in code.
2. Two Data Sources (One for each table), Two Indexers pointing at the same Index.
3. Using a SQL View, doing the join in it.

I'm using the first option as an Example, but I'm getting results between **200 to 400 ms** for only 3 records **-Using Postman**. The business limit will be around 20 results. My concern with this is when I start to add more indexes and then do the join between them in the code could be not performant.

Say for example the main table, with 4 or 5 tables related to it (PK - FK relationship), I would have to create an index for each one of them. Is that OK? Would that cause performance issues? Should I try the second or third option?

*Could you please expand your answer.*
*Thanks*

Comment: Hi Guiseppe, can you clarify what exactly you are trying to optimize for?  Is it latency of how long it actually takes to get your data in the index, or is it the latency in querying for the records you need and doing the joins you need across records passed on the results?  Also, are the joins you would be doing across these tables all on the same field, or do some tables join on field A while other tables join on field B?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the best way to design/create 1 or 2 indexes with the info from these two tables. (The relationship between them is 1 to many). But my concern is more about querying the records, and not updating the index. The last question about the Join I'm not sure I understood it right, but I think they always join on the same field. For example table A with PK called ID join Table B with FK Column called FK_TableA. Thanks!

Comment: Also, for the Second option I couldn't find any example about how to do it when the two data sources are SQL Azure DB tables.

Comment: You should be able to create two indexers that are pointing towards the same index and as long as you map the join field of the tables into the id field of the index, then the join will result in all documents with that id being retrievable at once, which would avoid you needing to do multiple queries and thus hopefully reduce the overall query latency.  However, I'm not sure how this would work in a 1 to many scenario.  Are you hoping to map each of the results from the second table in an array related to the first table?

Comment: I finally managed to get two indexers working toward one index. But yes, as you said, the relationship of 1 to many doesn't seems to work. I tried creating the index field as string colllection but it failed when a ran the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you look at the new complex type capabilities of Azure Search.  For 1:N relationships, you could put the related records in a Collection(Edm.ComplexType) field on the index.  More info on complex types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types

As far as indexers go, I'd recommend you create a view in SQL that pulls the related records for the current row into a JSON formatted text field.  You would then point the data source/indexer at this view and map the fields from the JSON field into a complex collection field in the index.

SQL actually makes defining the view pretty easy.  For example, for the Azure Search Hotels sample schema it would be:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Rooms$
    WHERE dbo.Rooms$.HotelID = dbo.Hotels$.HotelID FOR JSON AUTO) AS Rooms
FROM dbo.Hotels$
```

Hope this helps.

Mike Carter
Azure Search product team

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. In order to create a SQL view, I will have to implement the watermark policy so It can keep track of the latest changes, right? also, in the case where Hotel and Room are SQL tables (1:N), where should I create the watermark column? In both of them?, does that column should be also part of the select statement in the SQL view?

Comment: One more thing, I'm using .NET SDK to create the indexes, in this case, Collection(Edm.ComplexType) means Collection<Room_Class_Name> ?

Comment: If you want to pick up changes in either the parent or child table, the yes you should have a rowversion field in both.  You would surface the higher value in the view to make sure the changes are picked up by the indexer.  In the .Net SDK, you can work with complex types like they are objects in .Net.  Take a look at the sample for more info: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/DotNetHowTo

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have done the SQL View to pick up changes in either the Parent or Child table based on HighWaterMark policy.  Now, using the same example of Hotel and Rooms (1:N relationship), when a Room gets Deleted. What is the best way to handle row deletions in the Child table? Should I force the rowVersion column of the Parent table to increase, so it can detect changes?.

Comment: To detect Deletions in the Parent table I'm using Soft Delete policy, but I'm not sure how to handle deletions in the Child Table, since the parent table has an array of child table rows as currently is on the example of Hotel and Rooms.